# WooCommerce add product in cart with the same custom parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

In my shop I have my products with a checkbox before the "add to cart" button.
If the customer check this checkbox and add to cart, the value is send to the cart session.

The code of my checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="colissimo">
```

To output my checkbox value I use this in **`cart.php`**:

```
$cart_item['check'];
```

I want create a function to checkin mini-cart if there is a product with that checkbox.

Ex situation 1 :

The customer add to cart the product with the checkbox checked.
The customer go to another product.
In the product they have a checkbox but the customer not checked and add to cart.

The cart return false because it's not checked.

Ex situation 2 :
The customer add to cart the product with the checkbox NOT checked.
The customer go to another product.
In the product they have a checkbox but the customer check the chebox and add to cart.

The cart return false because it's checked.

I am trying to achieve this with the code below but it doesn't work:

```
function is_product_the_same_cat($valid, $product_id, $quantity) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
         return true;
    }
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

        $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        $target_terms = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $cat_ids[] =  $cart_item['check'];
        }

        foreach ($target_terms as $term) {
            $target_cat_ids[] = $cart_item['check']; 
        }           
    }
    $same_cat = array_intersect($cat_ids, $target_cat_ids);
    print_r ($same_cat);
    if(count($same_cat) > 0) return $valid;
    else {
        wc_add_notice( 'This product have not the same parameter!', 'error' );
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'is_product_the_same_cat',10,3);
```

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_product_the_same_cat($valid, $product_id, $quantity) {
    global $woocommerce;
    //si panier vide ok
    if($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
         return true;
    }


        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        $cat_ids[] = $cart_item['check'];
    }

    $coli = $cat_ids;

    if ((in_array("colissimo", $coli))){
        if ((in_array("colissimo", $coli)) && (($_POST['check'])==='colissimo')){

            return $valid;}

        else {

            wc_add_notice( 'Les produits Colissimo font l\'objet d\'un panier séparé !', 'error' );

            return false;
        }
    }else{
        if(!isset ($_POST['check']) ){return $valid;}
        else {
            wc_add_notice( 'Les produits Colissimo font l\'objet d\'un panier séparé !', 'error' );

            return false;
        }
    }


}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'is_product_the_same_cat',10,3);
```